# render child-route in parent router outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am working on a rather large application with a lot 'entities' that are quite interconnected. Let's simplify the application in a simple CRUD applicaiton, with lots of 'MasterDetail' screens for each type of entity.

(MasterDetail: Left a list/table of entities, right the detail when you click an item on the left)

As I said, lots of entities are 'connected' to other entities, so, from the detail, you can click to these other entities, which are sometimes rendered in again a MasterDetail, but for the sake of simplicity in this example, a Detail page with extra paging controls (so the the user can easily go to the next linked entity)

A lot of entity types are connected. To avoid cyclic dependency problems, we must make use of LazyLoading. (if we don't, we end up in one huge module, which is obviously not what we want)

I"ve set up an example:

A MasterDetail component with the list/table on the left and the detail on the right.

- The detail is rendered in a `router-outlet` inside the MasterDetail.
- The routes to connected entites must be 'child routes' since the routed component must have access the the DetailComponent (probably via component injection?)

Ok, and now the problem:
All works well, except, I can't get the ui right. When I click from a 'DetailComponent' to a connected entity, I don't want this to render inside the detailComponent, but completely under the MasterDetail.
In fact, I want the 'hide' (not destroy, since I need the state), the MasterDetail, so I can render the detail, takeing the full size that the MasterDetail was using.

I was thinking using named router-outlets whould be a solution, but I can't get it working.

You can find the example here:
https://ng-run.com/edit/KzNjVgPMhXNob3QekJyv

Any suggestions?

Comment: So which one should be? You'd like the _clicked detail_ to take all of `MasterDetail`'s space(without destroying it)  or you'd like to render it under `MasterDetail`?

Comment: In the example, when you click on products in the detail, I want the product detail take all of MasterDetail's space (while not destroying it)

Comment: If you want the `MasterDetail` component to not be destroyed, you might have to opt for a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`. I have some notes about it about it [here](https://github.com/Andrei0872/andreigatej.dev/blob/master/src/markdown-pages/blog/ng-router-indepth-overview.md#customizable-parts-of-angularrouter).